# ProgressBar when program is running

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I'm trying to add to my program progress bar ,when it executes.Actualy I want to add something like this:

```
public class TestProgressBar extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   public  TestProgressBar Bar;
    public TestProgressBar() {
        initComponents();
        Bar=this;
    }
public void start(){
      //progress bar action
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() { 
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){                
                          jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue()+10);  
                    try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                          Logger.getLogger(TestProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                      }
            }
              }
              });
        //program running
   while(true);
}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     TestProgressBar t=new TestProgressBar();
     t.setSize(320, 320);
     t.pack();
     t.setVisible(true);
     t.start();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

but it doesn't work
I found code that implements what i want to do
[Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java)
but for met it's messy
So the questrion is how to implement progress bar  which changes than program is working?
The progress bar value changes but form doesn't show these changes

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an exception? If there are no exceptions, what are the results and what were you expecting?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread which is putting your application to sleep. The `while (true)` may also be called on the event thread, but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Solution: don't step on the Swing event thread (or Event Dispatch Thread or EDT) but instead use a background thread for this. Please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to see how to use a SwingWorker to help you create a background thread for this.